# Can I have multiple favicons in D7

Tags: theming

This [favicon generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014823/does-a-favicon-have-to-be-32x32-or-16x16)) generates multiple favicon png files and code for the `<head>` section of your HTML pages. This is said to be better than a single favicon file which might not display correctly in some devices.

[image]

But I think "Path to custom icon" in D7's /admin/appearance/settings only accepts a single favicon file.

[image]

If so is there a way to use multiple favicon png files?

If I can only use a single image what is the best practice for the format of the file?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [Head Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/head):

> This module provides a range of metatags that can be added to the
>   document head of each available theme.
>
> In an attempt to keep themes clear of anything that could be
>   considered optional, i have aggregated all the frontend related
>   metatags you could ever need into one advanced theme settings page
>   which can be found at admin/appearance/advanced

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the Head Module, if you'd like to avoid the overhead of a module, would be to use `hook_page_alter()` in your theme's `template.php`. This is a code sample in one of my themes (replace `mytheme`):

```
function mytheme_page_alter($page) {
  $path = '/' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme');
  $apple = array(
    array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'href' => $path . '/images/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png',
    ),
    array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'sizes' => '76x76',
      'href' => $path . '/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png',
    ),
    array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'sizes' => '120x120',
      'href' => $path . '/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png',
    ),
    array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'sizes' => '152x152',
      'href' => $path . '/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png',
    ),
    // etc.
  );
  foreach ($apple as $link) {
    drupal_add_html_head_link($link);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you'd like to avoid overhead of a hook, you can directly put this in your theme's html.tpl.php file. I wouldn't however, use such hooks or anything just for a favicon (your snippet from the screenshot alone looks like to be 2kb, which can result in GBs with decent traffic).

Comment: @AyeshK that is only if you already use a html.tpl.php. If not, then the overhead of the file itself might be bigger than that of a hook. Besides, the need to use an Apple favicon or not comes presumably from the site's spec and it's not something a developer just decides, unless it's a personal matter. In this question's case, this is an entirely different matter altogether.

Comment: I disagree using a custom tpl.php file is a more overhead. Even of you don't specify a template file, Drupal will use the default one anyway, so it's just a matter of that file vs this file.

Comment: Maybe you're right on this one. I am not convinced at all for your previous strong but confusing statement about GB's in traffic. Mentioning GBs suggests HTML overhead (which seems important and inevitable for the question anyway) and nothing about the CPU overhead to parse the hook. Still, there is no performance measurements of one against the other so this is not a constructive debate anymore but only speculation. Feel free to post a separate answer if you have something better to suggest.

Comment: Sorry if my comments didn't really sound any positive. That GB count was not about your reply in particular. Just that this giant snippet can calculate towards many GBs in server traffic.

Comment: Pity for the downvote. Perfectly legit answer, solves the question's problem alternatively, effort in writing, but gets downvoted by someone and the only comment is by Ayesh K for unclear performance considerations. *When in fact what is recommended is better in performance than using a module as recommended by the top answer (which I do like tbh).

Comment: Sorry if you think I down voted this (it would be great if a mod could confirm this). I didn't downvote and I don't know why would anyone - this method is perfectly valid and to be honest, I would go for this instead of the Head module.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm a newbie, but the PHP code itself doesn't go to the client, does it? Only the generated header lines will get sent over the wire, so no matter how verbose the PHP is, it doesn't directly contribute to bandwidth usage. This is independent of the page generation time, which would be affected by CPU time, if the code is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new module just for that! Here you go: [Responsive Favicons](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_favicons)